# Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1

Tags: android, twitter

I want to integrate `Twitter sdk` to share, i am using `compileSdkVersion 22`, `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'`, Followed all the steps given on the `fabric site` but getting error which `gradle` sync

> Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
    dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Go through **[Twitter](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/twitter.html)**

Comment: @Pratibha No sorry .

Comment: Not a solution.  This is the exact code generating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did following changes into my internal build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }


}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }


}
```

and made following changes to the outer build.gradle file

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to  all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for future reference.
add below line of code at top module level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'realm-android'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

add google-services.json file in the main directory of module.

This is the reference site for how to integrate twitter login with firebase authentication
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login